# Change Div class depending on value with small increments

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a Div that can have about 100 different shades depending on the value of a variable which in this case is "votes". The more upvotes the redder the button. The more downvotes the bluer the button.

I can easily make a function like this with 8 classes :

```
$scope.divColor = function (votes) {
    if (votes < 60)
        return "blue60";
    else if (votes >= 60 && votes <= 69)
        return "blue70";
    else if (votes >= 70 && votes <= 79)
        return "blue80";
    else if (votes >= 80 && votes <= 89)
        return "blue90";
    else if (votes >= 90 && votes <= 99)
        return "red100";
    else if (votes >= 100 && votes <= 109)
        return "red110";
    else if (votes >= 110 && votes <= 119)
        return "red120";
    else if (votes >= 120)
        return "red130";
}
```

But is there anyway to have a variable somewhere that uses the votes value to set the actual background-color rather than the class?

Comment: No...it's not. CSS is not a programming language

Comment: You are correct so ill edit my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set a 1000% gradient background from red to blue then when the vote is updated, simply change its position on javascript: `document.getElementById("element").style.backgroundPosition = "0% 50%";`. Where min(red): `0% 0%` middle(purple): `0% 50%` max(blue): `0% 100%`

**UPDATE:** As you see below on the comments, use "100000%" instead of "1000%" to avoid any gradient shade of being noticed.

```js
function test(){

var votes = document.getElementById("test").value;  
document.getElementById("testobj").style.backgroundPosition = "0% " + votes + "%";
  
}
```

```css
.square {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, skyblue, tomato);
  background-size: 100000% 100000%;
  float:left;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

input {
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.A {
  background-position:0% 0%;  
}

.B {
  background-position:0% 50%;  
}

.C {
  background-position:0% 100%;
}

.D {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, skyblue, tomato);
  background-size: 100000% 100000%;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="square A">0%</div>
<div class="square B">50%</div>
<div class="square C">100%</div>
<input id=test type="range" name="votes" min="0" max="100" oninput="test()">
<div id=testobj class="D">Slider test</div>
```

Comment: I like it...I really do.

Comment: Thats actually brilliant and exactly what i need. Thanks very much.

Comment: One problem with this method is that you actually are seeing a bit of gradient at any time. This is more noticable when using black and white like here: https://jsfiddle.net/qd0yje93/

Comment: Just change 1000% for 10000% (or even 100000%) and you'll notice zero gradient.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by targeting the value like this in your css `input[value="1"]{}`

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vctbszc2/4/

html

```
<input type="button" value="1"><br>
<input type="button" value="2"><br>
<input type="button" value="3"><br>
<input type="button" value="4"><br>
```

css

```
input[value="1"]{
  background-color: blue;
}
input[value="2"]{
  background-color: red;
}
input[value="3"]{
  background-color: green;
}
input[value="4"]{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**So after reading Pulie's comments below, the closest you can get is something like this:** http://jsfiddle.net/6DAwY/952/

This will give you a range for 8 conditions. by using `input[value^="1"]` you are looking for a value that with the number 1, so 10,11,12.... then when you hit 20 it will use this css `input[value^="2"]` and so on.

html

```
<input value="0">
<input value="11">
<input value="23">
<input value="35">
<input value="42">
<input value="53">
<input value="65">
<input value="72">
<input value="86">
```

CSS

```
[value^="0"] {
  background-color: purple;   
}
input[value^="1"] {
  background-color: red;   
}
input[value^="2"] {
  background-color: green;   
}
input[value^="3"] {
  background-color: yellow;   
}
input[value^="4"] {
  background-color: blue;   
}
input[value^="5"] {
  background-color: orange;   
}
input[value^="6"] {
  background-color: grey;   
}
input[value^="7"] {
  background-color: lightblue;   
}
input[value^="8"] {
  background-color: lightgreen;   
}
```

Comment: That's a shipload of CSS for 100 colors though. Which was the point of the question, which was basically "How to do it without all that CSS?"

Comment: Yeah..but that's not the question. The OP wants 100 colors but just wants to use a variable in class name or attribute....which CSS doesn't support yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do everything you want to do in just CSS, but there several different ways to achieve the desired effect that involve both CSS and another language.

#### Option 1 : Setting inline CSS styles via JavaScript

Instead of changing the class of an element, you can directly change its styling, as suggested by [**Andrew Willems's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587492/change-div-class-depending-on-value-with-small-increments/35588890#35588890) :

```js
var votes = 0;

function shadeColor() {
    var numLvls = 25;
    var maxVotes = 200;
    var redVal = parseInt(parseInt(Math.min(votes, maxVotes) / maxVotes * (numLvls - 1)) / (numLvls - 1) * 255);
    var bluVal = 255 - redVal;
    color = "rgb(" + redVal + ", 0, " + bluVal + ")";
    return color;
}

function updateVotecount() {
    document.getElementById("voteCount").value = votes;
}

function vote() {
    votes = votes + 10;
    updateVotecount();
    document.getElementById("myShade").style.backgroundColor = shadeColor();
}

document.getElementById("myShade").style.backgroundColor = shadeColor();
document.getElementById("update").addEventListener("click", vote);
```

```css
#myShade, input {
    color : #FFF;
    disabled: true;
    background: transparent;
    border : none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myShade">
   Number of votes = <input id="voteCount" value="0">
</div>
<button id="update">Vote</button>
```

This option works in every browser, but it's still a pure JS option.

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qxnfss6c/11/))

#### Option 2 : Using a CSS pre-processor

Another option to consider would be the use of a [**CSS preprocessor**](https://github.com/showcases/css-preprocessors) language like [**Less**](http://lesscss.org/) or [**Sass**](http://sass-lang.com/), which adds not only variables but also [**mixins**](http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-basics-the-mixin-directive/), [**functions**](http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions) and a whole bunch of other interesting stuff.

In Sass, you could do something like this :

```
$votes : 20;

@function shade-color($votes) {
    $numLvls : 25;
    $maxVotes : 200;
    $redVal : round(round(min($votes, $maxVotes) / $maxVotes * ($numLvls - 1)) / ($numLvls - 1) * 255);
    $bluVal : 255 - $redVal;
    @return unquote("rgb(" + $redVal + ", 0, " + $bluVal + ")");
}

.shade {
    color: shade-color($votes);
}
```

This Sass code would produce the following CSS :

```
.shade {
    color: rgb(21, 0, 234);
}
```

Unfortunately, this adds another scripting language to your stack, which might unnecessarily complicate matters. Also, pre-processor languages aren't ideal when the values of your variables are updated often, as they need to be compiled into CSS before they can be used in a browser.

#### Option 3 : Combining CCS variables with JavaScript logic

The latest CSS specs do allow variables, which are accessible from JavaScript.

That means you could do something like this :

```js
var votes = 0;

function shadeColor() {
    var numLvls = 25;
    var maxVotes = 200;
    var redVal = parseInt(parseInt(Math.min(votes, maxVotes) / maxVotes * (numLvls - 1)) / (numLvls - 1) * 255);
    var bluVal = 255 - redVal;
    color = "rgb(" + redVal + ", 0, " + bluVal + ")";
    return color;
}

function updateVotecount() {
    document.getElementById("voteCount").value = votes;
}

function vote() {
    votes = votes + 10;
    updateVotecount();
    document.body.style.setProperty('--shade-color', shadeColor(votes));
}

document.body.style.setProperty('--shade-color', shadeColor(votes));
document.getElementById("update").addEventListener("click", vote);
```

```css
body {
    --shade-color : #000;
}

#myShade, input {
    color : #FFF;
    disabled: true;
    background: transparent;
    border : none;
}

#myShade {
    background : var(--shade-color);
}
```

```html
<div id="myShade">
   Number of votes = <input id="voteCount" value="0">
</div>
<button id="update">Vote</button>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qxnfss6c/12/))

Unfortunately, it's currently only supported by the following browsers :

- **Firefox 43** and up
- **Chrome 49** and up
- **Safari 9.1** and up

Pretty much every other browser (including Chrome 48, IE11 & Edge 14) do not support this feature, which means that you can't use it in production code yet.

Comment: That sets one color...now set the other 99 required. But that's not the question. The OP wants 100 colors but just wants to use a variable in class name or attribute....which CSS doesn't support yet.

Comment: @Paulie_D : Well, you actually can set the value of CSS variables from JavaScript, which would result in a CSS+JS hybrid solution. I just updated my answer to illustrate that!

Comment: This si in my opinion the most fully fleshed out answer with all different use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that provides a color from a blue-to-red spectrum that is divided into a particular number of discrete colors (`numLvls`). This requires setting a vote count for the "highest" color, i.e. red (`maxVotes`).

```
var redVal = parseInt(parseInt(Math.min(votes, maxVotes) / maxVotes * (numLvls - 1)) / (numLvls - 1) * 255);
var bluVal = 255 - redVal;
```

Put together the two, i.e. `"rgb(" + redVal + ", 0, " + bluVal + ")"` to get the CSS-friendly color string.

See the code snippet below for a demo. The example uses 5 color levels, not the 100 from your question, just for simplicity, but any value can be used.

```js
var votes = 0;
var maxVotes = 13;
var numLvls = 5;
var color = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";

report();

$("button").click(function(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === "up") votes += 1;
  else votes -= 1;
  if (votes < 0) votes = 0;
  var redVal = parseInt(parseInt(Math.min(votes, maxVotes) / maxVotes * (numLvls - 1)) / (numLvls - 1) * 255);
  var bluVal = 255 - redVal;
  color = "rgb(" + redVal + ", 0, " + bluVal + ")";
  report();
});

function report() {
  $("#votes").html("votes: " + votes + "<br/>color: " + color);
  $("#msg").css("background-color", color);
  $("#maxVotes").text("votes required for full red color: " + maxVotes);
  $("#numLvls").text("number of distinct color levels: " + numLvls);
}
```

```css
#msg {
  color: white;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="up">UP</button>
<button id="dn">DOWN</button>
<div id="msg">&nbsp;Something to be colored based on vote count</div>
<div id="votes"></div>
<div id="maxVotes"></div>
<div id="numLvls"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is setting a data attribute with a value with jQuery. And then you can use the value of the attribute in your css. It's very dynamic, so you don't need to write for each value style separately.

```
div { background-color: attr(data-color) }
```

Comment: Really? I don't think you'll find that's supported by any browser yet.

Comment: in the moment, unfortunately it only can be used as :after/:before 'content'.

Comment: That's true. I forgot. But if you want to use it, its possible ofcourse. Make your element relative, and the after or before pseudo absolute with a full width and height.